# how to open multiple windows of terminal in gnome-shell?

Tags: gnome3, gnome-shell

I am using xterm. I want to open two separate instances in arch linux. 
However when I click on the icon it does do any activity.

I have used Ubuntu before. It was normal to open multiple terminal in Ubuntu. Is it possible in Arch Linux? I am using gnome-desktop.

Comment: Try moving one of the windows to side. The two windows are probably overlapping so you cannot see the one on the bottom.

Comment: no, it is not opening. I have tried changing work-space and opening xterm there.

Comment: What desktop environment are you using? Opening multiple xterms is certainly possible in Arch. (I do it all the time.) So, most likely you are missing some package or dependency.

Comment: i am using gnome-desktop

Comment: This depends on the desktop environment. It doesn't depend on the distribution.

Comment: Wasn't aware of that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you stated you were using GNOME, I assume you're trying to open xterm from the [screen that pops up](https://www.gnome.org/wp-content/themes/gnome-grass/images/home/featured_image.png) on which your desktop applications are listed, right? (I think the scientific name for that screen is "Activities Overview". Anyway...)

Try holding down the `Ctrl` key while left-clicking on the xterm icon, that should open another instance.

Answer (score 0):

As i am using GNOME, We can `right click` on the icon which opens a selection menu then choose `open new window` from there.